# invalid identifier problem in oracle livesql

Tags: oracle, ddl

i have a pretty simple code just to see if my value that i insert into a column works but i am stuck with invalid identifier problem

```
create table person(
 ID_NO varchar(15),
 datelend DATE,
 constraint person_name_PK primary key(ID_NO));

 insert into person(ID_NO,datelend) values('sahil','2018-01-25');

 select* from person;
```

it shows that "ID_NO" is an invalid identifier and that name is already being used by an existing object.

Comment: You have probably already created a `person` table in your LiveSql session, hit the reset button to get rid of everything and start again. Remember that `'2018-01-25'` is not a date, you should always use an explicit date format `to_date('2018-08-25','yyyy-mm-dd')` will work

Comment: hi, anything on why "ID_NO" is an invalid identifier?

Comment: Presumably the table you had already created named `person` does not contain a column named `id_no`. You can check using `desc person`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works (although you probably want to insert a `DATE` literal rather than a string literal in your `INSERT` statement):

```sql
create table person(
  ID_NO varchar(15),
  datelend DATE,
  constraint person_name_PK primary key(ID_NO)
);

insert into person(ID_NO,datelend) values ('sahil', DATE '2018-01-25');

select * from person;
```

If it is not working in LiveSQL then you have probably already created the `person` table without the column. You can click on the "Actions" button on the SQL Worksheet and click "View Session" to see what commands you have already issued and, if you need to, you could click "Reset Session" to clear everything and then you can run your script and build the table without any existing objects to create a conflict.